# Conditional expectation of a stochastic process at stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability, stopping-times

If I have a discrete-time non-martingale random process $X_n$ such that $X_n$ is non-negative   and $E[X_n | X_0] \leq \delta$, $\delta > 0$, for all $n \geq 1$, then by using Markov's inequality, for $a > 0$, can I say the following:

$$P\left(\sup_{n \geq 1} X_n \geq a | X_0\right) \leq \frac{\delta}{a}  \ \ \ \ \ \  (1)$$

My reasoning is this:
From Markov's inequality, if we consider a stopped process $X^{*}_n$ with some stopping time $T=\inf{\{T \leq M : M \in \mathbb{N}, X_T \geq a\}}$, then we have

$$P\left(\max_{1 \leq n \leq M} X_n \geq a | X_0\right) = P(X_T \geq a | X_0) \leq \frac{E[X_T | X_0]}{a} \leq \frac{\delta}{a}$$

Now, by taking the limit $M \rightarrow \infty$, I can replace the $\max{}$ operator by $\sup{}$ to obtain (1). However, I'm not sure that I can just take the limiting operator when the process is not a (super/sub)martingale. So any leads in this regard would really help me. Particularly, is taking the limit operator right for me to do, and why?

Comment: No. Take $a=2$, $X_0=1$, $\delta=1$, $(X_1, X_2)  \in \{(0,2), (2,0)\}$ equally likely, $X_n=1$ for all $n \geq 3$.  Then $E[X_n|X_0]=1$ for all $n$ but clearly $\sup_{n\geq 1}X_n=2$ and so $P[\sup_{n\geq 1} X_n \geq 2] =1 > 1/2$.

Comment: @Michael thanks for pointing out the typo. I have now corrected it.

Comment: I deleted my comment on your typo.  However my remaining comment gives a counter-example to your claim. The limit has nothing to do with it.  You cannot conclude $E[X_T|X_0]\leq \delta$ with $T$ defined as a function of past $X_n$ values. This is not a martingale and you cannot expect to apply stopping theorems to general processes.

Comment: On an unrelated topic: I see you want to make $T$ some kind of stopping time, but I cannot understand the definition you stated: It looks like a circular definition of $T$ in terms of itself, and is not clear if the optimization variable is $T$ or $M$, and not clear what happens if $X_n<a$ for all $n \in \{1, ..., M\}$.

Comment: @Michael T is defined as the minimum time for which $X_n \geq a$, or if the condition never applies, stop the trial at some finite time $M$. Therefore the optimization variable here would be $T$. So if $X_n < a$ for all $n \in \{1,\ldots,M\}$, then we will have $T=M$.

Comment: I don't understand why I won't be able to conclude $E[X_T | X_0] \leq \delta$. Since $T \in \mathbb{N}$, and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, by definition I have $E[X_n | X_0] \leq \delta$, then it should also apply at time $T$.

Comment: Ohh, I guess then that the issue is taking a maximum or a supremum inside the expectation in the LHS of the Markov's inequality?

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with limits or the Markov inequality, see my counterexample in first comment, and my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  I gave a counter-example in my first comment, here is another one: Take $\{X_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ i.i.d. exponentially distributed with mean 1, so that
$$E[X_n|X_0]=1 \quad \forall n \in \{1, 2, 3,...\}$$
Clearly $\sup_{n\geq 1} X_n = \infty$ with prob 1 and so for any $a$:
$$ P\left[ \sup_{n\geq 1} X_n \geq a \vert X_0\right] = P\left[ \sup_{n\geq 1} X_n \geq a\right]= 1$$

---

Details:
Fix $\delta = 1, a=42$. Fix $M$ as a large positive integer.  Define $K$ as the first positive integer $n$ such that $X_n\geq 42$ (define $K=\infty$ if there is no such positive integer).  Define $T=\min\{M, K\}$.

We cannot claim $E[X_T|X_0]\leq  1$.  Indeed:

\begin{align}
E[X_T|X_0] &= E[X_T] \\
&= E[X_T|X_T\geq 42]P[X_T\geq 42] + E[X_T|X_T<42]P[X_T<42]\\
&\geq E[X_T|X_T\geq 42]P[X_T\geq 42] \\
&= (42+1)P[X_T\geq 42] 
\end{align}
Since $\lim_{M\rightarrow\infty} P[X_T\geq 42] = 1$ we get
$$ \lim_{M\rightarrow\infty} E[X_T|X_0] \geq  43$$